# Problem in Internal and external direct sums

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring. $M'$ and $M''$ are submodule of a $R$ module $M$ such that $M=M'\oplus M'$ (external direct product). Then $M=M'+M''$ and $M'\cap M''$=0

My problem is I only know $M'$ is isomorphic to $\{(m',0)|m'\in M'\}$. I couldn't say they are equal. Also I couldn't say the isomorphism which maps
$M'$ to $\{(m',0)|m'\in M'\}$ , also maps $M''$ to $\{(0,m'')|m''\in M''\}$

I only want to prove $M=M'+M''$ as the other one follows easily.
I was trying for hours but I couldn't prove it (it seems simple).  Please help

Edit (This is exact statement in the book)

> > Let $R$ be a ring. $M'$ and $M''$ are submodule of a $R$ module $M$ such that $M=M'\oplus M'$. Then $M=M'+M''$ and $M'\cap M''$=0

Comment: This is exercise in "A term in commutative algebra" by Allen altman and steven kleiman. Exercise 4.25

Comment: You need more information. Otherwise, take $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $M=C_2\oplus C_2$, $M’=M’’=C_2\oplus\{0\}$. Then it is certainly true that $M$ is isomorphic to the exzternal direct sum $M’\oplus M’’$, but it is not true that $M=M’+M’’$ or that $M’\cap M’’=0$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Oh, but the authors gave this in the exercise in the book. Is there any condition that implies external direct sum  is internal direct sum?

Comment: There could be some implicit hypotheses about *how* the isomorphism is defined. But, as you write it, it’s false.

Comment: What makes you think that writing an equal sign means “isomorphic to the external direct sum”? To me, that says “**is** the internal direct sum”.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin because in book they define only external direct sum (even atiyah did the same). Its is not "isomorphic to" it is actually the external direct sum. Sorry about that

Comment: They are being horribly sloppy, then, since $M’$ is not in fact a submodule of the external direct sum $M’\oplus M’’$; it is only *isomorphic* to the submodule of pairs $(m’,0)$. Which means the exercise is poorly written. It only makes sense if you actually *identify* $M’$ with $M’\oplus\{0\}$ and $M’’$ with $\{0\}\oplus M’’$, at which point the exercise is a triviality. Which is fine: the distinction between internal and external direct sum/product is mostly academic, but if they are going to gloss over it, they should not do it in a confusing way.

Comment: They did similar to what you are saying in solution.  But i couldn't understand what it means to identify $M'$ with $M'\oplus \{0\}$. Please explain it

Comment: The map $m\mapsto (m,0)$ is an isomorphism between $M’$ and $M’\oplus\{0\}$. So instead of thinking of $m\in M’$ as an element of just $M’$, you think of it as the element $(m’,0)$ of $M’\oplus M’’$.

Comment: But that only gives $M=N'+N''$ where $N'$ is isomorphic to $M'$ and not actual "=". But I think that's what they trying to say in the problem. Thanks for  helping me out. I really appreciate your help. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, that’s my point: they can’t mean equality if they mean external direct sum, which means they are being sloppy. That’s what I said four comments ago.

Comment: I understand it now. I was very confused.  Thanks for helping me out